# Good way to document controller actions in PHPDoc?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, comments

I'm trying to figure out a good way to document controller actions in a php mvc framework. It's really important to me that there is a way to stick the url for the action in there, my problem is that I cant seem to find a way to fit that into the schema for phpdoc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem/question.  You can put whatever you want to in a phpdoc block, including the relevant URL for a controller action (you can even use markup if you want):

```
/**
 * This is some foo action.
 *
 * URL: /foo/bar/baz
 */
public function fooAction(/* ... */) {
    // ...
}
```

That said, if you specifically want to use a custom tag like `@url` or something, then you just need to [use the `-ct` command-line option](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.command-line.customtags) to tell phpdoc that you don't want it throwing parse errors when it comes across your custom tag(s):

```
# Will specify custom tag @url
phpdoc -ct url ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the software you use to generate your documentation.

I had a similar problem and switched to [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). Doxygen allows you to add custom information to your doc comments like @action_url and can generate and can output HTML, pdf, man pages, etc...

Comment: I've done only a small amount of reading into doxygen. It'd help me out a lot if you could show example usage for a controller action?